# Create public transport lines map with the ArcGIS schematics extension

Tags: arcgis-desktop, schematics

I want to build a transport lines in a map schematics.Like the one we see on metro stations, I know that is possible with schematic extension of ArcGIS
[image: metro lines map]

Here some explications on how
[Create route maps with the ArcGIS schematics extension](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/create-route-maps-with-the-arcgis-schematics-extension/)

But I want an easy example.

Comment: I followed that explanation when overlaping the lines on schematic process I get the overlaping only on a one section between two nodes only .How to solve this isue? you can  check it here https://i.imgur.com/m7aOHBB.jpg

Comment: It is working now no isues

Comment: here the example, https://i.imgur.com/7JIfxmJ.png